# Current LXC support for Red Hat - How do I create a RHEL 6.x LXC container?

Tags: lxc

I have been working with LXC containers, the basic tutorials and some networking and it seems to me that its a very straightforward and simple way to create a pure distribution on top of my host.

Current list of templates available does not however list the RHEL x.x distribution. There is CentOS.

I see that Red Hat has supported some efforts in LXC with the libvirt driver, however that shows as deprecated on the site and everything is pointing to their Atomic host which I am experimenting anyways, however, that seems more of a docker way. There might be some variations of docker which ultimately may give me a bare minimum container running a full distro.

I am OK getting more into docker but what I expect at this moment is to run as a simple LXC container with RHEL 6.x distro. Is there no way to run a RHEL LXC container ?

Answer (score 0):

it is indeed unfortunate that redhat plans to discontinue libvirt support for lxc. even within rhel7, so that means rhel6 may be the last version where it will be supported for the lifetime of that release.

as an alternative, there are packages for lxc in epel: https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/repoview/lxc.html

they are even easier to use than libvirt-lxc

as for the template, in either case you should be able to use the centos template with little modification. all the packages are the same and really only the repo sources should point to redhat instead of centos.